# Отображение фигур поверх изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qpainter, paintevent

Встречаю эту проблему уже не первый раз. Нужно изобразить фигуру поверх изображения, но приоритет такой, что изображение отрисовывается всегда поверх всего.

Как управлять приоритетом?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QComboBox, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QListWidget, QFileDialog,
                             QTextEdit, QDesktopWidget, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.state = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        pixmap = QPixmap("file_name.png")
        lbl = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        lbl.setScaledContents(True)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.setFixedSize(1200, 1000)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.qp.setPen((QPen(QColor("green"))))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(100, 100, 30, 30)
        self.qp.end()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение моего вопроса.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 500, 300)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("file_name.png")
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
        painter.setPen((QPen(QColor("green"))))
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, 30, 30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил кнопку и один метод. Нажимаем кнопку. Зажмите кнопу мыши и протяните по холсту.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QComboBox, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QListWidget, QFileDialog,
                             QTextEdit, QDesktopWidget, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets   
from random import randint, gauss


SPRAY_PARTICLES = 100
SPRAY_DIAMETER  =  10

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#0000ff')
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)            

    def set_pen_color(self, c):
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(1)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)

        for n in range(SPRAY_PARTICLES):
            xo = gauss(0, SPRAY_DIAMETER)
            yo = gauss(0, SPRAY_DIAMETER)
            painter.drawPoint(e.x() + xo, e.y() + yo)

        self.update()


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QPainter и растровая графика")
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

        self.state = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        pixmap = QPixmap("im.png")
        self.label = Label()        #QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)   
#---        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Нарисовать много чего")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.draw_something)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)        #@
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None  # для рисования линии

#    def paintEvent(self, e):
#        self.qp = QPainter()
#        self.qp.begin(self)
#        self.qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
#        self.qp.setPen((QPen(QColor("red"))))
#        self.qp.drawEllipse(100, 100, 30, 30)
#        self.qp.end()

    def draw_something(self):
        # создаем экземпляр QPainter, передавая холст (self.label.pixmap())
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green"), 2))      
        painter.drawLine(*[randint(0, 400) for _ in range(4)])    # нарисовать линию.

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("red"), 5))      
        painter.drawPoint(*[randint(0, 400) for _ in range(2)])   #  рисует точку

        # drawRect, drawRects and drawRoundedRect
        # Все эти функции рисуют прямоугольники, определенные координатами x, y и шириной и высотой прямоугольника,
        # или экземплярами QRect или QRectF, которые предоставляют эквивалентную информацию.
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#EB5160"), 1))

        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(*[randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4)])))

        painter.drawRect(*[randint(0, 300) for _ in range(4)])


        # Методы drawRoundedRect рисуют прямоугольник, но с закругленными краями, и поэтому принимают 
        # два дополнительных параметра для радиуса x & y углов.
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#376F9F"), 2))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(*[randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4)])))

        # Существует необязательный конечный параметр для переключения между радиусами эллипса x & y углов, 
        # определяемых в абсолютных пиксельных терминах Qt.RelativeSize(по умолчанию) или относительно 
        # размера прямоугольника (передается как значение 0… 100). 
        # Передайте Qt.RelativeSize, чтобы включить это.
        #painter.drawRoundedRect(40, 40, 100, 100, 10, 10)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(*[randint(0, 255) for _ in range(6)])


        # Последний примитивный метод рисования, который мы рассмотрим сейчас, 
        # это drawEllipse, который можно использовать для рисования эллипса или круга.
        # В этом примере drawEllipse принимает 4 параметра, 
        # причем первые два - это позиция x & y верхнего левого угла прямоугольника, 
        # в котором будет отображаться эллипс, 
        # а последние два параметра - ширина и высота этого прямоугольника соответственно.
        # Вы можете достичь того же, передав QRect
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(3)
        pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor(204,0,0))  # r, g, b
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(10, 10, 100, 100)
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, 150, 200)
        painter.drawEllipse(200, 200, 300, 400)        

        # Существует еще одна сигнатура вызова, которая принимает центр эллипса в качестве первого параметра, 
        # предоставленного в виде объекта QPoint или QPointF, а затем радиус x и y. 
        painter.drawEllipse(QtCore.QPoint(400, 100), 10, 10)
        painter.drawEllipse(QtCore.QPoint(400, 100), 30, 50)      


        # Text
        # Наконец, мы кратко рассмотрим методы рисования текста в QPainter. 
        # Для управления текущим шрифтом в QPainter вы используете setFont, 
        # передавая экземпляр QFont. При этом вы можете контролировать family, weight and size  
        # (среди прочего) текста, который вы пишете. 
        # Однако цвет текста по-прежнему определяется с помощью текущего пера.

        #pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor(255,70,70))  # r, g, b
        #painter.setPen(pen)
        # Ширина пера не влияет на внешний вид текста.
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255,70,70), 12))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Times')
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setPointSize(20)
        painter.setFont(font)
        # Вы также можете указать местоположение с помощью QPoint или QPointF.
        painter.drawText(220, 30, 'Hello, world!')

        # Существуют также методы для рисования текста в указанной области. 
        # Здесь параметры определяют положение x & y, а также ширину и высоту ограничительной рамки. 
        # Текст за пределами этого поля обрезается (hidden/скрыт). 
        # Флаги 5-го параметра могут быть использованы для управления выравниванием текста внутри блока, среди прочего.
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(70,70,255), 0))
        painter.drawText(10, 60, 600, 100, Qt.AlignHCenter, 'Hello, world!')



        painter.end()                         # закрыть художник и применить изменения.

        # Обычно вам также нужно вызывать .update() для запуска обновления виджета
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Test()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]